# Android emulator not connecting to localhost via 10.0.2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, retrofit, retrofit2

My local API setup is running in `localhost:3000`on my Windows 10. I am using Retrofit to connect with APIs. I used `http://10.0.2.2:3000` for connecting Android emulator to Window's localhost. It was working fine for several months. One day it stopped working and I tried so many Google/Stackoverflow posts, but nothing helps. I tried in another newly installed machine and was not working. One day surprisingly it started working without any changes. Now I got my new PC and it is not working. Seems some instability with the 10.0.2.2 trick. Any ideas?

I am getting the below exception

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 3000) from /10.0.2.16 (port 51498) after 60000ms
```

Comment: Maybe Win10 has beeing updated??

Comment: @Tobey66 might be, but what is the relation with it?

Comment: Try using a different emulator or device to see if the issue is specific to the emulator you're using.

Comment: @user2357113 I tried with 5 emulators

Comment: have you tried by creating a new socket/port and connecting to it?

Comment: @FerroLuca I didn't get your question. Programmatically or some settings in my Windows host machine

Answer (score 0):

you can try hosting your application on your local IP instead of localhost and if you install that app on your mobile you just need to connect your mobile with the same wifi. Yeah due to some configuration issues your app may be run on localhost or may not so it's better to host your applications on local IP.

Try hosting your application on to the local IP and connect your phone with the same wifi or network. Such as:

For Wi-Fi connection

> Select Start > Settings > Network & internet > Wi-Fi and then select the Wi-Fi network you're connected to.
> Under Properties, look for your IP address listed next to IPv4 address.

For Ethernet connection

> Select Start > Settings > Network & internet > Ethernet.
> Under Properties, look for your IP address listed next to IPv4 address.

Which looks something like 192.168.x.x ex:- 192.168.0.100, 192.168.1.20..etc

open the terminal for that root folder which you want to host. Then run this command
If you are using laravel then

> php -S 192.168.0.100:8000 -t public

If core PHP

> php -S 192.168.0.100:8000

Just remember php command only runs if you defined the path in your environment or just simply install composer.

you need to change this IP with your IP 192.168.x.x and port for you will host I prefer 8000 and use that IP address with port in your Android app.